# How to use Azul's JSSE with TLS 1.3 support

Tags: java-8, tls1.3, adoptopenjdk

https://github.com/openjsse/openjsse

"The OpenJSSE project was created to add support for TLS 1.3 to existing Java 8 applications without requiring code changes"

How to use this project exactly?

I'm currently using the AdoptOpenJDK build for Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the issue log for openjdk ([Link](https://github.com/openjsse/openjsse/issues/5)):

> OpenJSSE for OpenJDK can be installed in two possible ways:
>
> - add OpenJSSE provider in the list of security providers of java.security file
> - registered at runtime with Security.insertProviderAt method
>
> However you'll better use Azul JDK8 builds as soon as it has preintegrated and fully tested support for OpenJSSE provider with -XX:+UseOpenJSSE